# How can I set an app pool restart schedule in IIS7 via WMI / Powershell?

Tags: iis-7, wmi

I am creating a function to manage App Pools in IIS7 to our desired specifications, and I am having trouble converting one line from our equivalent IIS6 script; to set the restart schedule.

In IIS6 the line was:

```
$newPool.PeriodicRestartSchedule = @( '6:15' );
```

The naive translation for IIS7 is:

```
$newPool.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Schedule = @('00000000061500.000000:000')
```

however this doesn't work because it throws the exception:

```
Exception setting "Schedule": "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' 
to type 'System.Management.ManagementBaseObject'.
```

How do I create this `ScheduleElement[]` array to assign to this value?

#### Edit: problem 1 down...:

```
$time = ([wmiclass]'root\WebAdministration:ScheduleElement').CreateInstance()
$time.Value = '00000000061500.000000:000'
$newPool.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Schedule = $time;
```

Problem 2: This value doesn't seem to save when I call `$newPool.Put()`. What's next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up and decided to use appcmd:

```
function CreateAppPool( [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$AppPoolName ) {
    PROCESS {
        $appcmd = 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\appcmd.exe'
        &$appcmd add appPool "/name:$AppPoolName" "/+recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='06:15:00']"
    }
}
```

I am still interested in seeing how this can be done without appcmd.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a post from a long time ago ... But I had issues too ano 2016, so posting here doesn't seem to be a bad thing.

I'm doing the job through Pascal Script and I am using different objects/properties. One of the main issues I had was that my time string wasn't ansi.

Here is a snippet of how it works for me (varAppPool is my app pool object):

```
WMI_IIS_ApplicationPool_SetSetting_Recycling(varAppPool, '00000000000000.000000:000', '00000000000000.000000:000');

function WMI_IIS_ApplicationPool_SetSetting_Recycling(varAppPool : Variant; strIdleTimeout, strPeriodicRestart: String):Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (WMI_IIS_Internal_CheckVariantIsNull(varAppPool, 'WMI_IIS_ApplicationPool_SetSetting_Recycling: {#WMI_IIS_errApplicationPoolIsNull}')) then
  begin
    varAppPool.ProcessModel.IdleTimeout := WMI_IIS_Internal_ConvertToAnsi(strIdleTimeout);
    varAppPool.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Time := WMI_IIS_Internal_ConvertToAnsi(strPeriodicRestart);
    try
      varAppPool.put_();
      Result := True;
    except
      Log('WMI_IIS_ApplicationPool_SetSetting_Recycling: Saving properties failed');
    end;
  end;
end;
```